# Trying to delete remote branch; listed locally, repos says it doesn't exist

Tags: git

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
I:\Work\bitbucket\test.gadget [master]> git remote update
Fetching origin
I:\Work\bitbucket\test.gadget [master]> git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/imagesTest
  origin/master
  origin/work2
I:\Work\bitbucket\test.gadget [master]> git push origin :imagesTest
Password for 'https://c_b@bitbucket.org':
error: unable to delete 'imagesTest': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://c_b@bitbucket.org/c_b/test.gadget.git'
I:\Work\bitbucket\test.gadget [master]>
```

How do I purge the reference to imagesTest from my local repository?
(Yes, I could start by cloning the remote repos. again, but I'd rather clean up the local copy...)
Thanks for any insights...

Comment: Would `git branch -D origin/imagesTest` work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remote branch was probably deleted by another person, but your local repo isn't aware of this until you run a `git fetch --prune`.

This command will delete from your local repo branches that doesn't exists anymore on remote.

Answer (score 3):

Your first command should use the `--prune` switch

```
git remote update -p
```

That will remove deleted remote branches from all the remotes that are updated

Comment: @Number8 You are welcome. The best way to say "thanks" on StackOverflow is to upvote. (Nudge, Nudge, Hint, Hint)

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use

```
git remote prune origin
```

I prefer to use less hyphens and other punctuation symbols.
Code and commands must flow like poetry so that we can type faster, write more!